# I'm stuck following a proof for the uniqueness of the solutions of the wave equation

Tags: solution-verification, advice

I'm trying to follow the prove that my math book provide for the uniqueness of the solutions of the wave equation, given certain boundary conditions.

It is as follows,

Defining $U=f_1-f_2$, where both $f_1$ and $f_2$ satisfy the wave equation and the same boundary conditions.

With $\psi=U$ and $\phi=\partial_t U=\dot U$, the Green's first identity reads,
$$\int_VdV\left[\dot U \Delta U + (\vec\nabla \dot U)\cdot(\vec\nabla U) \right]=\oint_S dS \left[\dot U \partial_nU\right]$$
Where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $\partial_t$ is the derivative normal to the surface.

After some steps, and using the fact that $U$ satisfy either $U|_S = 0$ or $(\partial_n U)|_S=0$, one gets

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}\int dV \left[\left(\dfrac{\dot U}{c}\right)^2+\left(\vec\nabla U\right)^2\right]=0$$
Now, the integral must be equal to a constant. Using $U|_{t=0}=0$ that constant is zero.

**Here is where I'm stuck**

$$\int dV \left[\left(\dfrac{\dot U}{c}\right)^2+\left(\vec\nabla U\right)^2\right]=0$$
The idea, of course, is to find that $U=0$, but the only argument the book gives is *'because inside the integral there is an addition of squares, $U$ must be constant and, because $U|_{t=0}=0$, that constant must be zero'*

I can't see why having that pair of squared terms inside the integral implies that $U=\text{constant}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The integrand of the integral is nonnegative because it is the sum of squares.
- If the integral of a nonnegative function is zero, then the function must be zero [almost everywhere].
- Thus $\dot{U}$ and $\nabla U$ are both zero.